# HTTP date format to NSDate

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdate, foundation

I have a date string (well, NSData, but that's easy to convert to a string) that's in what I believe is the format the HTTP standard uses:

```
Mon Apr 17 19:34:46 UTC 2006
```

Is there any better (i.e. less error-prone) way to parse that than specifying the format string by hand in an NSDateFormatter?

(My application is an iPhone app, but I suspect standard Cocoa solutions will work too, since NSDate and NSDateFormatter are part of Foundation.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question, you already have a NSDate and want to print it in a more user friendly format? If so why do you think it would be error-prone to use NSDateFormatter?

Comment: @Alexandre L Telles he doesn't have a NSDat*e*, but NSDat*a*, with a date string inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think there is a better way.

If you have some outside input, you must know the format of your input beforehand, and you can only prepare for problems, i.e. a fail over parser with an alternate NSDateFormatter.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.  Thanks anyway.